# Scatter Plotting an Image in a Pspicture with Polar-Type Coordinates

Tags: graphics, xetex, plot, pspicture, polar

I would like to be able to direct an image from a fixed point in a `pspicture` to various locations in the picture individual specifying angles and radii from that point.

Consider the code (which I compile with `xelatex`)

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

```
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(4,4)%
\psframe[fillcolor=blue!65!red,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=blue!65!red](-5,-5)(5,12)

\rput[tr]{-45}(1.75,1.75){\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=white]{63}}


\rput(-2,2){\includegraphics[width=2em]{example-image-b}}
\rput(-1,1){\includegraphics[width=2em]{example-image-a}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

In the case of the MWE, I would like to fix the Cartesian point (-1,1) (which contains Image A) and project it to the point (-2,2) (which now contains Image B) by specifying the angle (-45 degree) and a radius of \sqrt{2}. If this can be done, then I can proceed to scatter Image A (with various scaling factors individually assigned) to other locations in the `pspicture`. This would be a lot easier, I think, than using the common plotting method since the type of plotting I need this for involves thinking of the angles and radii prior to plotting the image.

QUESTION: How may I direct Image A from the Cartesian point (-1,1) to say, the following three locations: (1) angle=-45 (deg); radius=\sqrt{2}. (2) angle=90; radius=3. and (3) angle=30; radius=2.5?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind switching to `lualatex`, you can do this with [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html), wrapped up in `luamplib` which gives you full access to LaTeX packages for labels, and to a complete language for drawing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    fill unitsquare shifted -(1/2, 1/2) scaled 8cm
        withcolor 2/3[red, blue];
    
    label("\psvectorian[color=white, width=2cm]{63}", origin) rotated -45;

    label("\includegraphics[width=2em]{example-image-a}", sqrt(2) * cm * dir -45);
    label("\includegraphics[width=2em]{example-image-a}",         3 cm * dir 90);
    label("\includegraphics[width=2em]{example-image-a}",       2.5 cm * dir 30);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to produce a PDF file directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and for overlooking my error of -45 degrees in stating the problem, which should have been 135 degrees).  Although I had been looking for an answer that modifies the MWE, I nevertheless appreciate your answer Metapost approach---Metapost being something that I had wanted to become more familiar with.